# How to increase image quality with android cameraX library?

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, android-camera, android-camerax

I am creating an application which must implement its own camera.

I use the cameraX library provided by google.

I noticed that there is a difference between the quality of the image captured by my own application, and the image captured by the camera application installed on my phone.

although the 2 photos are captured with the same conditions (light, position...)

especially when I zoom the photo, the details of the image become more blurry to the image captured by my application

(in my own case, my phone is Google Pixel 5)

Please see these 2 photos to see the difference

[Image by phone camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLTpc.jpg)

[Image by my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEdLt.jpg)

And this is my code

```
/**
 *  Initialize CameraX, and prepare to bind the camera use cases
 */
private fun setupCamera()
{
    val cameraProviderFuture : ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
    
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
        
        cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
        
        lensFacing = when
        {
            hasBackCamera() -> CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK
            hasFrontCamera() -> CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT
            else -> throw IllegalStateException("Back and front camera are unavailable")
        }
        
        bindCameraUseCases()
        setupCameraGestures()
        
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
}



/**
 *  Declare and bind preview, capture and analysis use cases.
 */
private fun bindCameraUseCases()
{
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        
        val cameraProvider : ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProvider ?: throw IllegalStateException("Camera initialization failed.")
        
        // Try to apply extensions like HDR, NIGHT ##########################################
        
        val extensionsManager : ExtensionsManager = ExtensionsManager.getInstanceAsync(this@ImageCaptureActivity, cameraProvider).await()
        
        val defaultCameraSelector : CameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
            .requireLensFacing(lensFacing)
            .build()
        
        val finalCameraSelector : CameraSelector = if (extensionsManager.isExtensionAvailable(defaultCameraSelector, ExtensionMode.AUTO))
        {
            extensionsManager.getExtensionEnabledCameraSelector(defaultCameraSelector, ExtensionMode.AUTO)
        }
        else
        {
            defaultCameraSelector
        }
        
        
        // Get screen metrics used to setup camera for full screen resolution
        val metrics : DisplayMetrics = resources.displayMetrics
        
        val screenAspectRatio : Int = aspectRatio(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)
        
        val rotation : Int = binding.cameraPreview.display.rotation
        
        
        preview = Preview.Builder()
            // We request aspect ratio but no resolution
            .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
            // Set initial target rotation
            .setTargetRotation(rotation)
            .build()
        
        imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
            // We request aspect ratio but no resolution to match preview config, but letting
            // CameraX optimize for whatever specific resolution best fits our use cases
            .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
            // Set initial target rotation, we will have to call this again if rotation changes
            // during the lifecycle of this use case
            .setTargetRotation(rotation)
            .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY)
            .setJpegQuality(100)
            .build()
        
        imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            // We request aspect ratio but no resolution
            .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
            .build()
        
        imageAnalyzer?.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, LuminosityAnalyzer {})
        
        // Must unbind the use-cases before rebinding them
        cameraProvider.unbindAll()
        
        try
        {
            // A variable number of use-cases can be passed here -
            // camera provides access to CameraControl & CameraInfo
            camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this@ImageCaptureActivity, finalCameraSelector, preview, imageCapture, imageAnalyzer)
            
            // Attach the viewfinder's surface provider to preview use case
            preview?.setSurfaceProvider(binding.cameraPreview.surfaceProvider)
        }
        catch (exception : Exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}



/**
 *  [androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysisConfig] requires enum value of [androidx.camera.core.AspectRatio].
 *  Currently it has values of 4:3 & 16:9.
 *
 *  Detecting the most suitable ratio for dimensions provided in @params by counting absolute
 *  of preview ratio to one of the provided values.
 *
 *  @param width - preview width
 *  @param height - preview height
 *  @return suitable aspect ratio
 */
private fun aspectRatio(width : Int, height : Int) : Int
{
    val previewRatio : Double = max(width, height).toDouble() / min(width, height)
    
    return if (abs(previewRatio - RATIO_4_3_VALUE) <= abs(previewRatio - RATIO_16_9_VALUE))
    {
        AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3
    }
    else
    {
        AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9
    }
}



fun captureImage()
{
    if (!permissionsOk()) return
    
    // Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
    imageCapture?.let { imageCapture ->
        
        // Create output file to hold the image
        val photoFile : File = storageUtils.createFile(
            baseFolder = getOutputPath(),
            fileName = System.currentTimeMillis().toString(),
            fileExtension = StorageUtils.PHOTO_EXTENSION)
        
        // Setup image capture metadata
        val metadata : Metadata = Metadata().also {
            // Mirror image when using the front camera
            it.isReversedHorizontal = lensFacing == CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT
            it.location = locationManager.lastKnownLocation
        }
        
        // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
        val outputOptions : ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile)
            .setMetadata(metadata)
            .build()
        
        imagesAdapter.addImage(photoFile)
        
        // Setup image capture listener which is triggered after photo has been taken
        imageCapture.takePicture(outputOptions, cameraExecutor, object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback
        {
            override fun onImageSaved(output : ImageCapture.OutputFileResults)
            {
                val savedUri : Uri = output.savedUri ?: return
                
                StorageUtils.showInGallery(savedUri.path)
                
                binding.list.post {
                    imagesAdapter.addImage(savedUri.toFile())
                    binding.list.smoothScrollToPosition(imagesAdapter.itemCount)
                }
            }
            
            override fun onError(exception : ImageCaptureException)
            {
                exception.printStackTrace()
            }
        })
        
        binding.cameraPreview.postDelayed({
            binding.backgroundEffect.isVisible = true
            binding.cameraPreview.postDelayed({
                binding.backgroundEffect.isVisible = false
            }, AppUtils.VERY_FAST_ANIMATION_MILLIS)
        }, AppUtils.FAST_ANIMATION_MILLIS)
    }
}
```

How can I improve the quality of my images? Is there any thing I should do? is there a special filter or algorithm?

i need your help please

Comment: if you took photo on Pixel probably using default cam app (GCam) - this app is fulfilled with quaility improvements backed up by some AI. tought task to comptetite with the biggest in quality... try to take a photo with some 3rd party like [OpenCamera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera) and compare this picture with one got by your app

Comment: thank you @snachmsm for your reply. I noticed that this application provides the same image quality that I had with my application.. it cleared up my doubt that I'm missing something in my code, thank you :) but is there a possibility to achieve the maximum quality as google does? for example, is there a similar algorithm that I can integrate in my code?

Comment: at first: so let me post my comments as answer :) second: sadly I doubt that you will achieve bigGs quality or even get close to. thats their benefit for customers and a reason for buying Pixel - if anybody (any manufacturer) could use same alghoritms then  biggest con of Pixel series just disappear. you can try some basics - sharpening, brightness etc. but this is hard work to do... (at first: quality analysis, then decision: too dark, too blurry etc., at the end: applying changes, working with photo bitmap)

Comment: very logical.. thank you for this relevant information

Comment: worth noting: Google is packing up into Pixels relatively poor cam unit, they improving quality by alghoritms (looks like software > hardware). don't bother to much this "basic" quality as most manufacturers put same or even better cam in half-price units so most devices will give you at least this quality, probably better

Comment: I understand.. my application must provide images with a very good quality, because it must capture small details, such as letters and numbers on product labels.. I had doubt that something  I miss in my code, but your answer convinced me.. google has never tried to provide excellent hardware, it always wants to provide the best quality with the minimum possible hardware.. it will not be logical to give its algorithms to the public.. but as you said, the quality of the images captured by my application will be better on other devices with more powerful hardware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you took photo on Pixel probably using default cam app (GCam) - this app is fulfilled with quaility improvements backed up by some AI. tough task to comptetite with the biggest in quality... try to take a photo with some 3rd party like [OpenCamera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera) and compare this picture with one got by your app

Answer (score 1):

You can use CameraX Extension feature to enable HDR & Low light.
this improves the image quality significantly.

Comment: extensions are available only for few devices.. even my google pixel 5 doesn't support it. I don't know why google started supporting these extensions on samsung devices instead of their own devices

Comment: Yes, i remember earlier the support was there.
you can find the list of latest supported devices here,
https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/devices